# 2.79b, Cycles Render, Shade method Material, texture paint, hidden face is still being drawn

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, texture-painting

[image]

Hidden faces in texture paint mode are still being drawn in the Material shading method. Has anybody else encountered this problem, and how would one go about solving it?

Edit1: Got a confirmation that it is so by default, does it happen to any of you too on 2.79b? Tho I could swear it worked for me before.

Edit2: I'm going about it this way for I want "texture layers", that I have done on my actual work, in Material nodes to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties >>> Object >>> Dsiplay >>> Maximum draw Type >>> Solid (instead of Textured)

It won't display the material shading in Object_Mode (Ofc) but in Texture_painting the material will be displayed and it will allow you to actually hide the part of the mesh (For hiding in Maximum_draw_Type'Texture' seems to be a bugged).

Comment: Would Anybody wanna go about fixing it and sending us a build? :S

I wonder if its only 2.79b or this "bug" persisted for some time.